# Change displayed item in Stack View widget

Tags: android

I have a stack view widget can hold a variety of items. When I select an item I want it to go to the "front" of the list. I've currently been able to implement this.

The problem I'm having, is that I can't seem to figure out how to make the StackView "reset" itself or go back to displaying item 0. So what ends up happening is the user selects an item in the widget, but when they come back they have to manually scroll the widget back to item 0 to see that item since it's moved.

Is there any way to force the Stack View widget to "advance" or "move" to position 0? I've tried numerous different methods from the documentation but none seem to do the trick.

Thanks!